# Getting the table names

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show the table names on my website. At the moment there are two tables stored in my Database.

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row;
    }
} 
$conn->close();
```

The output is: ArrayArray

What do I have to do to get the names of the tables?

Comment: `var_dump($row)` instead of `echo $row`?

Comment: Never used show tables to get the table name but using information_schema.TABELS is better because then you can alias your columns names to use in PHP

Comment: You can also try `print_r($row)`. You can't use `echo $row` because `$result->fetch_assoc()` returns an array, and `echo` cannot print arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$row is an associative array, so you have to use specify name to read variable inside like this

```
echo $row['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row[0];
        echo "</br>";
    }
}
```

Or simply use the `echo $row[0];` instead of `echo $row;`

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me. :)     "i tried so hard but in the end it doesn't even matter"

Comment: @Luz If this answer solved your problem please feel free to mark it as answer to your question and to give cool_benn some rep for answering it.